# Get keys with highest values in object: javascript

Tags: javascript, object, key, key-value

I have to get highest keys with values in javascript object

```
var obj1 = {a: 1, b: 3, c: 2, d: 4};
var obj2 = {a: 1, b: 3, c: 2, d: 3};
```

I tried these codes 
code1

```
var max = Object.keys(r).reduce(function(a, b){ return r[a] > r[b] ? a : b });
```

code2

```
var max = _.max(Object.keys(obj), function (o) {return obj[o];});
```

code3

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null,Object.keys(obj).map(function(x){ return obj[x] }));
console.log(Object.keys(obj).filter(function(x){ return obj[x] == max; })[0]);
```

each code work ok in case of obj1, returns d because it's with max value 4
but in case of obj2 not return value according to my requirement it return only one key but I need all keys with highest values in case of obj2 requires the b & d because they both are highest value 4

Thanks
Dinesh

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this using underscore.js

```
var obj1 = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 2,
  d: 4
};
var obj2 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 3,
  c: 2,
  d: 3
};
//get the max
n = _.max(obj2, function(o) {
  return o;
})
//filter keys with max
j = _.filter(Object.keys(obj2), function(o) {
  return obj2[o] == n
})
//use map to get the key and value in an array
result = j.map(function(d){ return {key:d, value:obj2[d]}})
console.log(result)
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/prou1xzm/)

Another option using underscore chain [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/nu7mz95q/)

Comment: @Cyrill thanks for help, but on my local pc your 1st return error Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined at line "n = _.max(obj2, function(o) {"  and same error in code 2 at "n = _.max(obj2, function(o) {" and I only need key like ['b', 'd']

Comment: you will need to include underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/# cdn: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js

Comment: can I do with jquery & what about need only key

Comment: This is pure javascript https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/kzf5s4ry/ it will run anywhere without dependencies.